# Case in-sensitive search in array fields

Tags: arrays, regex, neo4j, cypher

I want to store an array to Neo4j db, Before knowing array field types, I was stored my array as an comma separated text field and used regex for find nodes that have an specific item!
Now i want to save array as an array field but i cant write a case insensitive condition with "IN" keyword!
There is my Regex for finding in cs-text field:

```
MATCH (user:USER)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group:SOME_GROUP) where 
group.resources =~ "(?i)(?:.*,|^)one_resource(?:,.*|$)"
RETURN group
```

My stored data was like this:

```
One_Resource,Another_Resource,...
```

And result was correct but i have some issues on retrieving this model and array field is better in retrieve.

Do you have any suggesting or method to solve this issue?

This is my Cypher for array field:

```
MATCH (node {hid:"abc"}) 
SET node.array_field = ["Foo","Bar","Baz","BaG"]
```

And finding with this:

```
MATCH (node) WHERE  "foo" IN node.array_field  RETURN node
```

But this is case sensitive :(

Thanks

Comment: Do you know about [**i flag**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).Please have a look at it. It is what you need

Comment: I used "i flag" in my Regex :`(?i)(?:.*,|^)one_resource(?:,.*|$)`, But as i know in array field can't use regex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded my answer in the book: [Learning Cypher](https://neo4j.com/books/learning-cypher/)

Must use `ANY (...IN...WHERE...)` in WHERE clause:

```
MATCH (node)
WHERE ANY ( item IN node.array_field WHERE item =~ "(?i)foo" )
RETURN node
```

Now can use Regex to finding wanted node.

There are four collection predicates. They are as follows:

- ANY: This predicate returns TRUE if at least one item in the collection adheres
  to the expression
- ALL: This predicate returns TRUE if all items in the collection adhere to the rule
- NONE: This predicate returns TRUE if no item in the collection follows the rule
- SINGLE: This predicate returns TRUE if exactly one item follows the rule

If we want all books tagged as NoSQL but not as Neo4j, we can use the NONE predicate
as follows:

```
MATCH (b:Book)
WHERE ANY ( tag IN b.tags WHERE tag = 'nosql' )
AND NONE ( tag in b.tags WHERE tag = 'neo4j' )
RETURN b.title,b.tags
```